# Syntax sugar for setting value as array of unwrapped value or empty

Tags: swift

I am trying to do this:

```
var arrayOfValues: [nonOptional]

if let unwrappedValue = optionalValue {
  arrayOfValues = [unwrappedValue] 
} else {
  arrayOfValues = []
}
```

Is there a one-liner for this?

```
arrayOfValues = [unwrappedValue?] ?? []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't bad. It's not terrible to be verbose here.

That said, this is a bit shorter and simpler:

```
[optionalValue].compactMap { $0 }
```

Create an array with the optional value in it. Then call `compactMap` with which returns an array of items where the block result is non-nil.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
arrayOfValues = [optionalValue].compactMap{$0}
```

or

```
arrayOfValues = optionalValue != nil ? [optionalValue!] : []
```

Comment: You and Alex answered the same thing-- but I think he answered first which is why I accepted his.